# Why does this array-field query fail in Mongoose but not Mongo shell?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my `User` schema in Mongoose.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    accounts: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account'
    }]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

In mongo shell, this finds my existing user document:

`db.users.find({ accounts:"57d03b30edfd30e806fb20c9"})`

But with Mongoose, this finds the empty set:

```
User.find({ accounts: "57d03b30edfd30e806fb20c9" })
    .exec(function (err, users) {

       *** users == [] ***

    });
```

Comment: since there is no type checking, in mongoshell you are really querying a string. perhaps in mongoose, you might consider changing the schema to simple String

Comment: But then I couldn't "populate" Account documents in Mongoose, right? Ah - I copied the wrong thing - that is supposed to be ObjectID - will correct now...

Comment: why do you use mixed? instead ObjectId?

Comment: also note in mongoose documentation There is this "Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs." http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html (mixed is not part of the valid lists)

Comment: in short, you can still "populate" but use supported type like ObjectId, Number,String,Buffer. type "mixed" is not part of supported use for "ref"

Comment: I set the type in that 'accounts' array to 'String' and everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, if the schema matches, you should just treat ObjectId as a string

```
accounts: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Account'
}]
```

then query it like it is a string

```
User.find({ accounts: "57d03b30edfd30e806fb20c9" })
.exec(function (err, users) {

   *** users == [] ***

});
```

but you need to delete the previous entry, since it is currently a "mixed" type.  I am guessing mixed is really just a string, so you could try to use string type like below. well, the fact that you could query a string in mongoshell and find a result

```
  accounts: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    ref: 'Account'
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.find({ accounts: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("57d03b30edfd30e806fb20c9") })
```

or alternatively...

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
User.find({ accounts: ObjectId("57d03b30edfd30e806fb20c9") })
```

As @vdj4y mentioned, Mongoose is interpreting your query as a String instead of as an ObjectId (which I imagine it is?)

Comment: This did not work at first, because I probably had an actual String in the database as test data. Eventually, I dropped the collections and used this. This is correct.